# how to change uiimageview image's programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

In my ios application i create uiimageviews programmatically like that,

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

                                   productID=[products objectAtIndex:i];

                                   UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                                   [button setFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+38 , row*350+8, 159, 45)];
                                   //[button setImage:redButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                   [button addTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(buttonAction:)
                                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                   button.tag = productID;
                                   [scrollView addSubview:button];



                                   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+170, row*350+25, 13, 13)];
                                   imageView.tag=productID;
                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage.png"];
                                   [imageView setImage:image];
                                   [scrollView addSubview:imageView];


                               }
```

in my buttonActon, i want to change that uiimageview's image to another image. But i can not do that. Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: You can not do this because? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try like this ,

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

                                   productID=[products objectAtIndex:i];

                                   UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                                   [button setFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+38 , row*350+8, 159, 45)];
                                   //[button setImage:redButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                   [button addTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(buttonAction:)
                                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                   button.tag = 100+productID;
                                   [scrollView addSubview:button];



                                   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+170, row*350+25, 13, 13)];
                                   imageView.tag=productID;
                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage.png"];
                                   [imageView setImage:image];
                                   [scrollView addSubview:imageView];


                               }
```

keep this one in button action method and pass the imageview tag in the place of `imgview.tag`

```
     UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:imgview.tag];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"];
```

Comment: i did same code but i got  this error :-[UIRoundedRectButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8993130

Comment: ok problem is that with tag value both the button and image having same tag value.

Comment: in the place self.view replace scrollView.

Comment: give different tag values for both images and buttons then it'l work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
imageView.tag=UrunId;
```

Write:

```
imageView.tag = productID + 100;
```

Because you need a unique tag for each Image View.

Then implement the `buttonAction:` like:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
  UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:(sender.tag+100)];
  [imageView setImage:yourImage];
}
```

Comment: because @Sunny gives the answer a few seconds ago before you. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this one

You should have different tag for button and image.So please give first different tag like this....

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+170, row*350+25, 13, 13)];
                                   imageView.tag=button.tag+1;
                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage.png"];
                                   [imageView setImage:image];
                                   [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

After that do this...

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
  UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:sender.tag+1];
  imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];

}
```